# Can you change the difficulty settings in System Shock after you start the game?

Tags: system-shock

I'm finding that I don't like the difficulty options I chose at the start of System Shock.  Is it possible to change them part-way through the game, either via an in-game option or even possibly by editing a save file?  It would be frustrating if I have to start completely over at this point.

Comment: Good question. The game difficulty settings are probably in chunk 4001 in save games, but I've never seriously investigated this. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 2):

There's no in-game way to change the difficulty settings.

In the save file, they are stored at [offsets 0x15-0x18 of chunk 4001](https://github.com/ToxicFrog/ss1edit/blob/master/doc/map.txt#L38). Unfortunately, chunk 4001 is stored compressed, so you can't just open SAVGAMXX.DAT in a hex editor and change the settings.

Your best bet is to use something like [ss1edit](https://github.com/ToxicFrog/ss1edit/) to decompress the save file, then edit it (I use `dhex` here, but of course any hex editor will do):

```
$ bin/res --decompress --in-place --res SAVGAM00.DAT
$ dhex SAVGAM00.DAT
```

In a decompressed save file, the difficulty settings will be found near (not necessarily at, depending on the preceding chunks) bytes 0x2C0-0x2C3 of the file; in any case they will always be found 0x15 (21) bytes after your character name, which should appear early in the file, a few bytes after the name of the save file itself.

You could also unpack the chunk and edit it directly, which entails a few more steps but means you don't need to worry about finding the right address, since it'll always be at 0x15-0x18:

```
$ bin/res --extract --res SAVGAM00.DAT 4001
$ dhex 04001.ss1map
$ bin/res --update --res SAVGAM00.DAT --in-place 4001
$ rm 04001.ss1map
```

I haven't tested this extensively, but it does seem to work. Changing the combat difficulty to 0 won't make enemies that are already hostile passive, but newly spawned enemies will be, and changing the puzzle difficulty to 0 will make puzzles you haven't already solved auto-solve when accessed, for example. Mission difficulty is the setting I'd most expect to have to weird long-term effects when changed, especially if you have it on a low setting, bypass some major objective that isn't mandatory on that difficulty, and then turn it up to a difficulty level where it is mandatory.

Don't forget to keep backups!